# sorting a list by names in python

Tags: python

I have a list of filenames. I need to group them based on the ending names after underscore ( _ ). My list looks something like this:

```
[
    '1_result1.txt',
    '2_result2.txt',
    '3_result2.txt',
    '4_result3.txt',
    '5_result4.txt',
    '6_result1.txt',
    '7_result2.txt',
    '8_result3.txt',
]
```

My end result should be:

```
List1 = ['1_result1.txt', '6_result1.txt']

List2 = ['2_result2.txt', '3_result2.txt', '7_result2.txt']

List3 = ['4_result3.txt', '8_result3.txt']

List4 = ['5_result4.txt']
```

Answer (score 2):

This will come down to making a dictionary of lists, then iterating the input and adding each item to its proper list:

```
output = {}
for item in inlist:
    output.setdefault(item.split("_")[1], []).append(item)

print output.values()
```

We use setdefault to make sure there's a list for the entry, then add our current filename to the list. `output.values()` will return just the lists, not the entire dictionary, which appears to be what you want.

Comment: You mean `item.split("_")[1]`, I think.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed those issues.

Comment: perfect. Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

using `defaultdict` from `collections` module:

```
from collections import defaultdict

output = defaultdict(list)
for file in data:
    output[item.split("_")[1]].append(file)

print output.values()
```

using `groupby` from `itertools` module:

```
data.sort(key=lambda x: x.split('_')[1])
for key, group in groupby(data, lambda x: x.split('_')[1]):
    print list(group)
```

Comment: if this helped you, please do accept it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Python 2.4, both list.sort() and sorted() added a key parameter to specify a function to be called on each list element prior to making comparisons.

The value of the key parameter should be a function that takes a single argument and returns a key to use for sorting purposes. This technique is fast because the key function is called exactly once for each input record.

So if `l` is the name of your list then you could use something like :

`l.sort(key=lambda s: s.split('_')[1])`

More information about key functions at [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Key_Functions)